# What should I use for high dynamic flex app? UIComponent or drawing every frame by myself?

Tags: apache-flex, rendering, visualization, flash-builder

Well, I'm used to develop visualization tool with OpenGL, so I always keep lists of data Objects and render them by go through the lists and draw them in rendering function. I'm wondering whether I could still use this pattern in flex application? It's to override the updateDisplayList() with graphics.clear() and series of draw..... to repaint all the things. I'm afraid this method would be efficient, but sometimes I feel it very flexible, esp. in some high dynamic application (for example, games).

So I'm eager to know what you will use in this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL's approach is completely procedural, while flash's and flex' is declarative. I would split scene into some parts (game objects) and update each as needed. Maybe even sprites instead of UIComponents, you can add them to Application with rawChildren.addChild - sprites are more lightweight. In short - don't put everything into one graphics object, this will decrease performance badly.